# Get data from an array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have such an array as below;

```
//var tt is from console.log
var tt =[
         {"price":50,"quantity":1,"sku":1},
         {"price":70,"quantity":5,"sku":2}
        ];
```

NB: var tt is an array I get when I do console.log; of which when I store it as above to var tt, it works normally.

I have tried the following;

```
 console.log(tt.price);//this give me 'undefined'
 console.log(tt['price'];//this also gives me 'undefined'
```

Anyone who knows how to access values from such an array?

Answer (score 2):

You have to choose an element from the array before accessing the price member.

```
console.log(tt[0].price);     // 50
console.log(tt[1]['price']);  // 70
```

Comment: Hello @Willis Blackburn, strangely, that too returns 'undefined'

Comment: Then the code you're running isn't what you've posted in the question. I ran it in the browser console and it worked. Provide a link to JSFiddle or something like that and I'll take a look.

Comment: The value for var tt I copy-pasted from console, because if indeed you run as it is, it will work with your solution, am guessing the values from the console is treated differently when stored in a variable, trying to figure out the mystery behind it

Answer (score 1):

It is an array of objects, so you have to use the array syntax to access the object and then you can use the attribute name.

```
tt[0].price
```

This is what you want.

Comment: var tt is an array I get when I do console.log; of which when I store it as above to var tt, it works as you have suggested, does it need to be converted to something first?

Comment: No, that way is ok accordingly to JSON notation.

Comment: I also thought I was doing something wrong, found out values displayed in console cant be somehow treated as in the case of var tt, though they seem to hold same arrays. Still trying to figure out what is happening here

Answer (score 0):

`console.log()` is actually a function in js, which does not return anything.
So if you say you are assigning a `consoloe.log()` to `var tt` then you are actually getting `undefined` in the variable because the function returns nothing.

```
var tt = console.log([
         {"price":50,"quantity":1,"sku":1},
         {"price":70,"quantity":5,"sku":2}
])
//therefore
console.log(tt) or 
console.log(tt[0]['price'])
//will give you undefined.
```

if you are doing this

```
         //first
var tt = console.log([
         {"price":50,"quantity":1,"sku":1},
         {"price":70,"quantity":5,"sku":2}
        ])
        //second  
        console.log(tt)
```

Then it will first print the array from the first console.log 
and then print undefined from the second.
var tt will still have no value assigned to it and will give you undefined.